# How to Kill Vapor Server

Tags: ios, swift, server, kill, vapor

I'm trying to build a very simple service using Vapor. It depends on websockets, and I establish a connection between an iOS device in simulator and vapor running on localhost.

When I want to make changes to the server, I restart and sometimes get `[ ERROR ] bind(descriptor:ptr:bytes:): Address already in use (errno: 48)`

I don't know how to find and kill this process, which is a socket running on 8080. I have to restart to get out of it, and I feel like throwing the computer out the window after a few repetitions (question about that already asked in mentalHealthOverflow.com).

How can I find and kill this process? Stopping the simulator device doesn't do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Kill a Vapor Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004411/how-do-i-kill-a-vapor-server)

Comment: Clearly not, Mike. We had a power outage here in dear old Phnom Penh, and I wasn't aware my original posting had not been lost.

Comment: This question discussed a lot of times in Discord chat. Simplest way to kill the process is to open `Activity Monitor`, search for process with name `Run` (or how your app called) and just force kill it. It is the problem in the latest Xcode that it wont kill the process properly with `kill 9` command.

Comment: thanks! I found the discord #vapor stream, much better than most documentation....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fix is actually pretty easy. Go to your terminal and run `lsof -i :<port>`, so in your case, `lsof -i :8080`. You will get an output of all the processes that are running on that port.

```
COMMAND   PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Run     48904 calebkleveter   31u  IPv4 0x97c38af35a1b4785      0t0  TCP localhost:Run (LISTEN)
```

You can then run the `kill` command, passing in the `PID` from the output you got:

```
kill 48904
```

You can now run your Vapor service.

Answer (score 6):

Oneliner that I use:

```
lsof -i :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN | awk 'NR > 1 {print $2}' | xargs kill -15
```

Which basically just sends `PID` of the Vapor process (running on the port 8080) to the `kill` command as argument